# Find all homomorphisms from a quotient polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X] /(15X^2+10X-2)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm completely lost, what my problem is I don't get the gist of a quotient polynomial ring nor ANY homomorphisms between it and some $\mathbb{Z}_n$, much less ALL of them. 
I know there is something to be done with an ideal, but I really have no clue how to do it. I would be grateful for a full solution or at least anything that may help me understand these structures.

EDIT:
Ok, so this particular polynomial was inreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, but I still have no clue how to deal with other cases, where it is reducible, for instance $X^2+3X+3$. I really would like to know how to solve problems of this kind.

Comment: Ok.. Does $15x^2+10x-2$ reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but it seems that it is with roots $\frac{1}{15}(-5-\sqrt{55})$, $\frac{1}{15}(-5+\sqrt{55})$.

Comment: you don't bother about that...see for anon's hint (a kind of answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: a ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z[X]/(\cdots)\to\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ will be determined by where $X$ is sent. It can't be sent just anywhere; it still has to satisfy $15X^2+10X-2=0$ (does this have roots in $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$?).

Comment: This is a very clear, elegant point.. I was unnecessarily making mess :D Good One :)

Comment: I feel hummiliated with my ignorance, but I don't know how to find roots of $15X^2+10X-2$ in $\mathbb{Z_7}$. Even though, do I have to show that this polynomial is a kernel of those homomoprhisms?

Comment: @surykatka There are only seven elements in $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$. Just check each one of them to see if there is a root. (In general, though, you can use the quadratic formula in any ring that doesn't have positive even characteristic, as long as you include all possible square roots.) For your second question: Since the element $X$ in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[X]/(\cdots)$ satisfies that polynomial, its image in $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ must also satisfy that polynomial (do you know why?).

Comment: Note that modulo $7$ the polynomial can be simplified to $X^2+3X-2=(X-2)^2+1$

Comment: I really don't see any roots. I checked for every element of $\mathbb{Z_7}$ and can't find equality to $0$. This $(X-2)^2+1$ has to be divideable by 7, but surely I cannot conclude that $(X-2)^2$ has to be divideable by 6?
And for the second case: I don't know why it has to satisfy the polynomial in both cases, because it is a homomorphism? When it comes to algebra, there is a little I know...

Comment: @surykatka You are correct, there aren't any roots. That means there aren't any homomorphisms! Check for yourself that if $f:R\to S$ is a homomorphism and $p(\cdot)$ is an integer-coefficient polynomial, that $f(p(r))=p(f(r))$ for all $r\in R$. Therefore, if $r$ is a root of $p$ in $R$, we may conclude its image $f(r)$ is a root of $p$ in $S$. Does this make sense?

Comment: What a relief, so for this case it does make sense to me, thanks a lot! But what if we had for instance $X^2+3X+3$? This polynomial indeed has roots both in $\mathbb{Z_7}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. So do I need only to say that roots of this polynomial in $\mathbb{Z_7}$ are the image of roots in $\mathbb{Z}$?