# Homomorphisms from quotient polynomial rings to some $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm completely lost, my problem is I don't get the gist of a quotient polynomial ring nor ANY homomorphisms between it and some $\mathbb{Z_n}$, much less ALL of them. I know there is something to be 
done with an ideal, but I really have no clue how to do it. I would be grateful for a full solution or at least anything that may help me understand these structures. 
For instance:

a) from $\mathbb{R[x]}/(X^2+1)$ to $\mathbb{C}$,

b) from $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(X^2+3X+3)$ to $\mathbb{Z_7}$,

c) from $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(10X^2-6X-3)$ to $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$.

Here [Find all homomorphisms from a quotient polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X] /(15X^2+10X-2)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629005/find-all-homomorphisms-from-a-quotient-polynomial-ring-mathbbzx-15x210) some my doubts were indeed dispelled, but I would like to see a full solution of another case.

Comment: For a) you could define $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $p\mapsto p(i)$. Then check if the restriction to $\mathbb{R}[x]/(X^2 + 1)$ is well defined

Comment: For such $\phi$ $X^2+1$ would be a kernel, but what restrictions do you mean? I don't really take hints as I literally know little of rings.

Comment: Look at the long answer below, this is what I meant (maybe badly expressed). I'd recommend studying some rings if you have trouble with the basics. It'll be pretty hard otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Consider the assignment $\phi:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $x\mapsto i$. First show this is a homomorphism. Next show it is onto. Then show that the kernal is $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle$. Finally use first isomorphism theorem. That will give you one isomomorphism.

What happened in that setting? Everything in $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle $ had to go to zero. That makes sense because $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle $ is zero in the quotient so it better end up at zero in $\mathbb{C}$. How can we define another map?

b) Think about the same thing here. Try the map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ by $\phi(x)=1$ and see what happens. What is special about $1$? Can you find other maps?

c) Do the same as $b$.

Comment: Ok, so I know how to show it is a homomorphism, and probably also how to show that the kernel is the polynomial given (because its image obviously is $0$),  but how can I prove that it is onto? Furthermore, I'm not sure what isomorphism theorem do you think of and finally - I think this gives me the biggest wonder - "why $X^2+1$ is zero in the quotient".

Comment: Onto is much easier than you think. Complex numbers are of the form $a+bi$ so if you know what polynomials go to $a$ then you should know that goes to $a+bi$.

Comment: @surykatka The fact about $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle$ being zero is just by the nature of quotient rings. Just like in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ we have everything divisible by $7$ is now zero in the quotient. For the theorem look up "First Isomorphism Theorem" in your book.

Comment: I don't remember hearing this theorem in my classes, nevertheless it's really helpful. But I still can't show two things: that it is onto and that $ker{\phi} \subset \langle X^2 + 1 \rangle$, I think I omitted this part, my intuition tells me that showing that the polynomial is in kernel may not be sufficient. And as far as I'm considered understanding these two things would help me solve another two examples because they're completely analogic?

Comment: I moved my issues to a new question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637478/understanding-the-homomorphisms-from-quotient-polynomial-rings

Comment: @surykatka Think about the onto case. Given any polynomial $a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$ consider the polynomial $a+xb$ where does this thing go? That will show onto. For your last kernal argument. Let $f(x)\in\ker\phi$ then we have that $f(i)=0$. So $i$ is a root of $f$. Therefore so is $-i$. Thus both $(x-i)$ and $(x+i)$ are factors of $f$. Therefore $x^{2}+1$ is a factor of $f$ and $f\in \langle x^{2}+1\rangle$.