# No ring homomorphisms $f: R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle \to K$ if $p(x)=0$ has no solutions in K.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I encountered this claim [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629005/find-all-homomorphisms-from-a-quotient-polynomial-ring-mathbbzx-15x210). In general it would read:

Let $R$ and $K$ be commutative rings with unity. There are no homomorphisms $f: R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle \to K$ if $p(x)=0$ has no solutions in $K$.

This is probably very basic question but I'm still not sure if I understand correctly why the above works. Here's my thought process:

Let's denote $p(x) = \underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}} a_kx^k$. It is clear to me that since $f$ is a ring homomorphism we have $f(0_{{}_R} + \langle p(x) \rangle) = 0_{{}_K}$. I can also see that $f(p(x)) = \underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}} f(a_kx^k) = 0$ yields the desired result if $f$ is a function from $R[x]$.

But $f$ is a function from $R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$, so I'm not sure why it would be legal to 'invade' the coset $(0_{{}_R} + \langle p(x) \rangle)$ with this function.

Comment: Have you thought through the example (using familiar objects) $\Bbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Note that the condition "$p(x)=0$ has no solutions in $K$" requires some more properties relating $R$ and $K$ to even be meaningful.  It always will be meaningful with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ since then there's a unique ring homomorphism $R\to K$, with which $K$ becomes an $R$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you over-generalized. The statement "$p(x)=0$ has no solutions in $K$" makes no sense without further assumptions, since $p(x)$ has coefficients in $R$ and there is no multiplication between elements from $R$ and $K$.

If $K$ however is an $R$-algebra, which means that $R$ comes equipped with a ring homomorphism $\varphi:R\to K$ then the statement makes sense, since you can use $\varphi$ to transform the coefficients of $p(x)$ from $R$ to $K$.

The correct statement would then be:

> There are no $R$-algebra homomorphisms $ R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle \to K$ if $p(x)=0$ has no solutions in $K$.

This is because if $f: R[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle \to K$ is an $R$-algebra homomorphism, then for $s=f([x])$

$$
0=f([0])
=f([p(x)])
=f([\underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}} a_kx^k])
=\underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}} f([a_k])[x]^k])
=\underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \varphi (a_k)s^k=:p(s)
$$

The stronger requirement that $f$ is a homomorphism of $R$-algebras ensures that $f([r])=\varphi(r)$ for all $r\in R$.

In the linked question $R=\mathbb Z$, $K=\mathbb Z_n$ and in this case any ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\to \mathbb Z_n$ is automatically a $\mathbb Z$-algebra homomorphism.

Comment: You beat me to it.  One issue though: It seems your corrected statement should be about $R$-algebra homomorphisms extending $\varphi$? (possibly abusing notation by using the terminology we'd use for field extensions --- maybe "compatible with $\varphi$"?)  I'm open to being mistaken here, but it seems $p(x)=0$ might have solutions in $K$ under one choice of $\varphi$ while having none under another choice.

Comment: @BrianMoehring We are given two $R$-algebras $\varphi:R\to K$ and $j:R\to R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, where $j(r)=[r]$. Then an $R$-algebra homomorphisms $f: R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\to K$ is by definition a ring homomorphism with $f\circ j=\varphi$, so i consider $\varphi$ and $j$ fixed.